# Create simple display

Tags: c, io, console

Sorry for this simple question but I don't really understand how correctly create consol on C. I wanna have several dynamic lines that will be update. I know that I can use `\r` but it is only for one line. I want for several lines. `system("cls")` not working good for this. Maybe you can help me.

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int currInt = 0;

    while (true) {
        system("cls");

        printf("%d", currInt);

        currInt++;

        if (currInt == 5) {
            currInt = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I will be have asynchronous input data that will be display on several lines and I need have update this screen. I think about `system("cls")` but it not clear screen in loop. Endless loop is important.

Comment: you have to use `curses` / `ncurses` library for that. Not possible with just printf

Comment: "Create simple display", funny title. Display something is probably is hardest thing to do in C.

Comment: Can you suggest me articles or libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it that `printf()` will help you achieve your goals. If I were you, I would give a shot with [Ncurses](https://www.viget.com/articles/game-programming-in-c-with-the-ncurses-library). Check this question too: [Where can I find a complete reference of the ncurses C API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109855/where-can-i-find-a-complete-reference-of-the-ncurses-c-api)

If this library won't satisfy you, then I would suggest [curses.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html). However I doubt this will do, since Ncurses is a modern implementation of the original curses.

---

For Windows: [Is ncurses available for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows)

Comment: What about windows?

Comment: Thanks. I will be try this library